# Swagger-ui-express swagger-JsDoc error  Could not render n, see the console. in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-jsdocs

I have a NodeJs app using swagger-ui-express swaggerJsDoc. When expand schemas as swagger define encountered error below. What should I do ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF23B.png)

[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6mqt.png)

[swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP3IP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.